# AVPlayer - how to turn CC coming from HTTP Live Streaming video on/off programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode6, avplayer

I am trying to create a **custom video player**. I am using SwiftUI (v1 and XCode 11.5) and am trying to allow the user to chose whether to turn **on/off** **CC** and also choose the language wanted.

How could one achieve this? What I've tried so far is setting the **appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically** property of the **AVPlayer** to **true**. Then the CC are shown if enabled from my iPhone's **Accessibility** settings.

```
avPlayer.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = true
```

I also tried ignoring system preferences by setting it to false and then using the isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled property to enable the CC but it didn't achieve my expected effect (isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled is also deprecated).

```
avPlayer.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = false
avPlayer.isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled = true
```

However I need them to be shown/hidden **programatically** (when a button is pressed for example) and the OS' settings about captions should be ignored. Also I would like to choose the **language** of the CCs. Is this even achievable?

*NOTE: The video I am playing is streamed from **Vimeo** if that matters.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should get all avaliable CC from your stream and then select one you need e.g.:

```swift
let asset = player.currentItem?.asset
if let group = asset?.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .legible) {
    let listCC = group.options
    if let firstCC = listCC.first {
        player.currentItem?.select(firstCC, in: group)
    }
}
```

In case to disable CC simply call:

```swift
player.currentItem?.select(nil, in: group)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had really hard time going through documentation and finding this on my own. Do you mind sharing how did you get your hands on this information?

Comment: @DI.dev I've been working for years with streaming playback on iOS and the best source of info it's documentation, apple's samples/presentations and of course Stackoverflow )

Comment: Note that the `mediaSelectionGroup` call will block the current thread unless you've asynchronously loaded the `availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions`